# Are there any specific tools for troubleshooting Domain Controller & Client connectivity?

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I am setting up a test rig on Amazon Web Services comprising of 2 web servers, 1 database server and 1 domain controller. All the servers are Windows Server 2012. I have had random occurrences of the web servers losing [trust with the domain controller](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771040). I am led to believe that there could be an issue with firewall settings/dns between the client and dc.

Is there any tool that can help me sort out connectivity issues between domain controller and client? I have tried Port Query tool from Microsoft.

I have disabled Windows Fire Wall and enabled AWS firewall rules for the purpose of ruling out any unforeseen blockages.

thanks,
SDG

Comment: `I have tried Port Query tool from Microsoft` - What specifically did you try with PortQry? Can you give us the symptoms of the problem, including any error messages you're seeing? How do you have the DNS client settings configured on **ALL** servers?

Comment: Disabling the Windows firewall is almost never the solution. Don't be distracted with the Windows Firewall as it's likely a red herring. I've never seen a domain communication problem that was caused by the Windows Firewall. My suggestion would be to turn it back on as that is the natural state for a Windows machine. Don't deviate from the default state, it will only serve to convolute the troubleshooting process.

Comment: I am running this command from WEB1 right now:     dcdiag /E /S:DC1

Comment: > `I am led to believe that there could be an issue with firewall settings/dns between the client and dc`. Why?  You're starting with conjecture right out of the gate, and not even providing a basis for it. It's unlikely that a computer would lose its trust/secure channel due to lack of connectivity for a short period of time. PortQuery provides all the tests needed for a point in time verification of connectivity.

Comment: `I am running this command from WEB1 right now: dcdiag /E /S:DC1` - That tells us nothing and it doesn't address any of the questions or points in my original comment. What are we to make of the fact that you're running `dcdiag /E /S:DC1`?

Comment: Results from PortQry is here:

Comment: **Results from PortQry**       UDP port 137 (netbios-ns service): LISTENING or FILTERED

Using ephemeral source port
Attempting NETBIOS adapter status query to UDP port 137...

NETBIOS name for 10.0.0.227 not found (timeout)
Adapter status query failed.
UDP port: FILTERED

Comment: **Results from dcdiag.exe** 
         The event log Directory Service on server DC1.SMALLBUSINESS.LOC could

         not be queried, error 0x6ba "The RPC server is unavailable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To directly answer your question, useful tools are Ncdiag and Nltest as well as Portqry.  Nltest is included with Windows and Ncdiag should be on the domain controller.  I prefer Nmap to Portqry as it's syntax is easier.  Besides Ping, scan from the server with the issue for ports 88 (Kerberos), 123 (ntp), 389 (LDAP) and 135 (RPC mapper) as open on the domain controller.  A nmap example:  nmap -p 88,123,135,389  IPaddressOfDomainController
2. You mention your issue is the domain trust.  Make sure their time is synced.  Member servers should be getting their time from the domain controller.  Check registry HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32tm\Parameters.  The value NtpServer should be set to NTDS5.  On the domain controller, you have the option of using a reliable Internet time source, such as time.nist.gov.  Use the command "w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update" then restart the W32Time service.  (Reference:  [“It’s Simple!” – Time Configuration in Active Directory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nepapfe/archive/2013/03/01/it-s-simple-time-configuration-in-active-directory.aspx))
3. What about DNS?  Your DC should be a DNS server; your member servers should use the DC as their DNS server.  In turn, unless you don't use the Internet, the DC DNS should forward all other requests to your cloud DNS servers (what you see if you DHCP.)
4. I agree - do not turn off the firewall.  Most Windows features will automatically add any rules needed.  But you might double-check that the active firewall profile on the DC is domain.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised everyone mentioned portqry but no one talked about portqryUI - it's not just a nice GUI wrapper of portqry, it includes a bunch of pre-defined testing sets. "Domain and trust" is one of the test sets, it tests all the ports needed for AD to work.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you that **PortyQryUI** is a more practical choice. I have been using the **Domain and trust** option for troubleshooting